# Meaning of Memory support for Ryzen

Tags: memory, amd-ryzen

I have no clue about the msi website what the memory support by Rx-1x00, A- Series, Rx-2x00G/GE, and what Rx-2X00 means. I am going to use a ryzen 7-2700X: so what category would it be in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What category would it be in?

- Rx-1x00 are the Ryzen Summit Ridge CPUs
- Rx-2x00G/GE are the Ryzen Raven Ridge CPUs with integrated Vega GPUs
- Rx-2X00 are Ryzen Pinnacle Ridge CPUs
- A-Series are Athlon processors

> I am going to use a Ryzen 7-2700X

You have a Ryzen Pinnacle Ridge CPU.

[Ryzen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryzen)

Comment: A-Series is an entirely different product line and has no connection to your Ryzen processor.